# jquery: определить номер нажатого элемента, номер родителя нажатого элемента среди других элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, counter

Подскажите, можно ли реализовать следующую вещь:

есть объекты

```
<div class = 'items'>
    <div class = 'item'><div class = 'object'></div></div>
    <div class = 'item'><div class = 'object'></div></div>
...
    <div class = 'item'><div class = 'object'></div></div>
</div>
```

есть обработчик

```
$('.items').on('click', function(e){
    if (e.target) && !$(e.target).parent().hasClass('object'))
        return;

// вот тут определяю что нажат object например второго item'а
});
```

**P.S.**

понимаю, что заметно проще просто каждому элементу добавить свой id или другой атрибут, по которому и выискивать, типа `my_id = '123'`, но интересовал именно способ как обойтись без дополнительного изменения html кода элементов

```
<div class = 'items'>
    <div class = 'item' my-count = '1'><div class = 'object'></div></div>
    <div class = 'item' my-count = '2'><div class = 'object'></div></div>
...
    <div class = 'item' my-count = '1000'><div class = 'object'></div></div>
</div>

$('.items').on('click', function(e){
    if (e.target) && !$(e.target).parent().hasClass('object'))
        return;

    let count = parseInt($(e.target).parent().attr('my-count'));
});
```

**P.P.S.**

Или это изврат и не париться и сделать так как написал выше (просто через уникальные атрибуты)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я верно понял задачу... При клике на текст в alert будет возвращаться порядковый номер элемента item, начиная с 0:

```js
$('.items .item').on('click', function(e){
   alert($('.item').index( this ));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
    <div class="item"><div class="object">Test 1</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="object">Test 2</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="object">Test 3</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="object">Test 4</div></div>
    <div class="item"><div class="object">Test 5</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let count = $(e.target).closest('.items').find('.item').
      index($(e.target).closest('.item')) + 1;
```